# How to type a (double) quote in Slack for Windows

Tags: keyboard, slack, diacritics, smart-quotes

In most (if not all) Windows apps if I type a (double) quote it does not immediately appear and waits for the next character. If a vowel, it will turn into a diacritic like ü or é, if a space (or actually anything that cannot use such a 'modifier') the quote appears: " or '.
Fine, this is how my system (keyboard) is set up.
If I need a quote instead of the modifier my brain knows to type <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>space</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> for "u

My Slack for Windows behaves differently:

- It handles <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> for ü
- It refuses to handle <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>space</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> for "u
  Instead the top hamburger menu drops open when I press the space bar.

How can I block that last behavior?

Notes:

- It's not that typing a space *always* opens the menu; that would be hell ;-)
  This happens only with space after a single or double quote.
- A colleague just told me he does not see that behavior

BTW <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>"</kbd> results in "", so that's no solution either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had a brainwave:

I have [PhraseExpress](https://www.phraseexpress.com/) running on my machine and that intercepts the keyboard as well. After stopping that and restarting Slack the behavior is as expected with a US International keyboard setting:

- <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> gives ü
- <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>space</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> gives "u

(*I considered just deleting my question, but who knows, this may help someone somewhere sometime*)

Answer (score 0):

PhraseExpress was the culprit here for me too. Same config: Windows 10 and US International Keyboard settings.

I need both apps running, so, **while having Slack windows focused**, I right-clicked PhraseExpress icon and **deselected** "*Detect typing on Slack*".